Como alterar a ordem dos fatores no eixo x do gráfico com ggplot2
Minha variável está com as seguintes informações:
H1
        1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9 
2.0383404 1.8159832 1.3828402 1.7176845 2.1172450 1.7641513 1.9149592 2.2764227 1.8691503 
       10        11        12        13        14        15        16        17        18 
0.8159206 1.3759293 2.0422802 1.7177790 2.1467069 1.6821608 1.8776331 1.5601782 2.1066628 
       19        20        21        22        23        24        25        26        27 
2.5448239 2.4000201 2.0851261 1.5697170 1.3886069 1.6747003 2.0600799 2.3156498 1.8779800 
       28        29        30        31        32        33        34        35        36 
1.9996530 2.4976951 1.5419764 1.9834932 1.9713327 1.6065228 1.7298201 2.0126926 1.1275348 
       37        38        39        40        41        42        43        44        45 
1.4611291 2.2055984 1.6963750 1.3337448 2.0414910 2.6911708 2.2434521 2.5294555 2.6935552 
       46        47        48 
2.0341960 2.7750777 2.8078837 

dput(H1)
structure(c(`1` = 2.0383404, `2` = 1.8159832, `3` = 1.3828402, 
`4` = 1.7176845, `5` = 2.117245, `6` = 1.7641513, `7` = 1.9149592, 
`8` = 2.2764227, `9` = 1.8691503, `10` = 0.8159206, `11` = 1.3759293, 
`12` = 2.0422802, `13` = 1.717779, `14` = 2.1467069, `15` = 1.6821608, 
`16` = 1.8776331, `17` = 1.5601782, `18` = 2.1066628, `19` = 2.5448239, 
`20` = 2.4000201, `21` = 2.0851261, `22` = 1.569717, `23` = 1.3886069, 
`24` = 1.6747003, `25` = 2.0600799, `26` = 2.3156498, `27` = 1.87798, 
`28` = 1.999653, `29` = 2.4976951, `30` = 1.5419764, `31` = 1.9834932, 
`32` = 1.9713327, `33` = 1.6065228, `34` = 1.7298201, `35` = 2.0126926, 
`36` = 1.1275348, `37` = 1.4611291, `38` = 2.2055984, `39` = 1.696375, 
`40` = 1.3337448, `41` = 2.041491, `42` = 2.6911708, `43` = 2.2434521, 
`44` = 2.5294555, `45` = 2.6935552, `46` = 2.034196, `47` = 2.7750777, 
`48` = 2.8078837), dim = 48L, dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", 
"27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", 
"38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48"
)), class = "table")

E estou com esse código que gera um gráfico de barras:
grafico <- data.frame(X=names(H1), Y=H1)
ggplot(grafico, aes(y=Y, x=X)) +
  geom_col(fill=gray(.3)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 3), breaks=seq(0, 3, .5)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=mean(grafico$Y),
             color="red", size=2, linetype="dashed") +
  theme_classic(base_size=16) +
  xlab("Parcelas") + 
  ylab("Índice de diversidade de Shannon–Weaver (H)")

Porém, a ordem dos fatores no eixo x do gráfico não aparece em ordem crescente, como esperava que acontecesse.

Como resolver isso?

O problema está em names(H1). Note que a ordenação de números no R, quando eles estão representados como caracteres, não obedece aquilo que intuitivamente esperamos:
sort(names(H1))
#>  [1] "1"  "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15" "16" "17" "18" "19" "2"  "20" "21" "22"
#> [16] "23" "24" "25" "26" "27" "28" "29" "3"  "30" "31" "32" "33" "34" "35" "36"
#> [31] "37" "38" "39" "4"  "40" "41" "42" "43" "44" "45" "46" "47" "48" "5"  "6" 
#> [46] "7"  "8"  "9"

Portanto, transforme estes valores de caracteres em numéricos:
sort(as.numeric(names(H1)))
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
#> [26] 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48


grafico <- data.frame(X = as.numeric(names(H1)), Y = as.numeric(H1))

Agora é só plotar o gráfico e obter o resultado esperado:
ggplot(grafico, aes(y = Y, x = X)) +
  geom_col(fill = gray(.3)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 3), breaks = seq(0, 3, .5)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(grafico$Y),
             color = "red", linewidth = 2, linetype = "dashed") +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16) +
  xlab("Parcelas") + 
  ylab("Índice de diversidade de Shannon–Weaver (H)")


Created on 2024-05-14 with reprex v2.1.0

